# How to get a random birthday in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to simply get a random birthday by using the following code:

```
DOB = random.choice(["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", 
"10", "11", "12"]) + "/" + random.choice(["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", 
"07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", 
"20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28"]) + "/" + 
random.choice(["1980", "1981", "1982", "1983", "1984", "1985", "1986", 
"1987", "1988", "1989", "1990", "1991", "1992", "1993", "1994", "1996", 
"1997", "1998", "1999", "2000"])
```

In some cases it's printing, 12/07/30512 or some other random date that I don't need. Why is this happening, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seems there are other codes affecting the results.

Answer (score 0):

In the fourth line, you end the line with a plus and nothing more, this is invalid syntax, to break expressions between lines they have to be between parentheses.

```
DOB = (random.choice(["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", 
"10", "11", "12"]) + "/" + random.choice(["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", 
"07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", 
"20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28"]) + "/" + 
random.choice(["1980", "1981", "1982", "1983", "1984", "1985", "1986", 
"1987", "1988", "1989", "1990", "1991", "1992", "1993", "1994", "1996", 
"1997", "1998", "1999", "2000"]))
```

I executed your code in 5000 iterations and i couldn't see the error.

```
import random
for i in range(0,5000):
    DOB = (random.choice(["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", 
    "10", "11", "12"]) + "/" + random.choice(["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", 
    "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", 
    "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28"]) + "/" + 
    random.choice(["1980", "1981", "1982", "1983", "1984", "1985", "1986", 
    "1987", "1988", "1989", "1990", "1991", "1992", "1993", "1994", "1996", 
    "1997", "1998", "1999", "2000"]))
print(DOB)
```